# vim in ConEmu - strange issue during scrolling

Tags: vim, conemu

I have a problem with colors when I scroll the page. Check the below gif:
[image]

This is a minimal vimrc to reproduce this: https://gist.github.com/lkurylo/f6a20801b48133a71fac
With the configuration for encoding, I must change the codepage (chcp 65001) before I launch vim in console.

I have no idea what can be wrong.

The same issues I have e.g. with the seoul256 theme. Don't know if this is a ConEmu issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been fixed in ConEmu 151025

Answer (score 0):

The apparent problem is that when scrolling up (aka "reverse indexing"), the shifted-in lines are colored.  Some terminals do this, some do not.  And some color one type of clearing operation, but not others.  If vim does not expect that behavior, it will not amend the coloring to work around unwanted coloring.

If this were a normal terminal with a terminfo/termcap, the place to look would be at the `bce` (back_color_erase) capability.  That is, if the terminal description does not have `bce`, but should, then there will be miscoloring.

For further reading:

- [My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches) (ncurses FAQ)
- [What $TERM should I use?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_terminfo) (xterm FAQ)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it issue by turning on Bufferheight mode on,
But this forced the theme of Conemu to be on instead of my VIM colorscheme.